# Loop in Rcpp slower than those in R

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, armadillo

I am converting a loop in R (which is slow when sample size is large) to Rcpp. Here is the loop in R

```
loop_R = function(R, V, iV, X){
  Rhat <- matrix(0, nrow = n, ncol = 1)
  for (j in 1:n) {
    r <- R[-j]
    VV <- V[-j, -j]
    iVV <- solve(VV)
    # version using global mean: This works best
    bbhat <- solve(t(X) %*% iV %*% X, t(X) %*% iV %*% R)[1]
    v <- V[j, -j]
    Rhat[j,] <- as.numeric(bbhat + v %*% iVV %*% (r - bbhat))
  }
  Rhat
}
```

Here, R and V are Matrix and iV is just the inverse of V, X is a model matrix (see examples below).

Then I wrote my first ever Rcpp function and saved it as `loop.cpp` file:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec loop_cpp(const arma::vec& R, const arma::mat& V, const arma::mat& iV, const arma::mat& X) {
  // Initiate Rhat
  int n = R.size();
  arma::vec Rhat(n); // to save results
  arma::uvec idx(n); // to identify elements to remove
  idx.fill(1.0);

  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    idx(j) = 0.0;
    arma::uvec idx2 = find(idx);
    arma::vec r = R.elem(idx2); // r[-j]
    arma::mat VV = V.submat(idx2, idx2); // V[-j, -j]
    arma::mat iVV = arma::pinv(VV);
    arma::mat bbhat = arma::solve(trans(X) * iV * X, trans(X) * iV * R);
    double bbhat1 = as_scalar(bbhat.row(0));
    rowvec v1 = V.row(j);  // V[j, ]
    vec v = v1.elem(idx2); // V[j, -j]
    double res = bbhat1 + as_scalar(trans(v) * iVV * (r - bbhat1));
    Rhat(j) = res;
    idx.fill(1);
  } 

 return Rhat;
}
```

And then using `Rcpp::sourceCpp("loop.cpp")` to make it available in R.

I then generated some data in R:

```
library(lme4)
mod <- lme4::lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject), data=sleepstudy, REML = F)
Y <- model.frame(mod)[, 1]
X <- model.matrix(mod)
n <- dim(X)[1]; p <- dim(X)[2]
D <- attr(mod, "pp")$LamtUt
V <- crossprod(D) + diag(n)
iV <- solve(V)
bhat <- solve(t(X) %*% iV %*% X, t(X) %*% iV %*% Y)
fitted.values <- X %*% bhat
R <- Y - X %*% bhat
# because I do not know how to deal with sparseMatrix in RcppArmadillo
R = as.matrix(R)
V = as.matrix(V)
iV = as.matrix(iV)
```

Both function `loop_R()` and `loop_cpp()` give the same results, which is good. However, `loop_cpp` is about 6 times slower than `loop_R`.

```
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(loop_R(R, V, iV, X), loop_cpp(R, V, iV, X), times = 10)
    Unit: milliseconds
                  expr       min        lq      mean   median        uq       max neval cld
   loop_R(R, V, iV, X)  523.8825  560.5022  606.5602  582.310  627.7818  797.0094    10  a 
 loop_cpp(R, V, iV, X) 3181.5071 3227.8532 3382.4447 3390.097 3471.1332 3735.6973    10   b
```

Since this is my first Rcpp function, I am not sure what happened. Can someone explain and improve the `loop_cpp`? Thanks so much!

### update

After replacing `pinv()` with `inv()` within `loop_cpp()`, the cpp version is slightly faster than the R version, but still not too much faster to worth the effort... hum...

Also, how can I deal with singular matrix? How to test whether a matrix is singular in c++?

```
Unit: milliseconds
                   expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
    loop_R(R, V, iV, X)  406.0211  411.2906  438.0069  415.2752  418.6047  547.2976    10  b 
  loop_cpp(R, V, iV, X)  384.2119  386.4745  389.2240  388.3505  392.5422  395.2945    10 a  
 loop_cpp2(R, V, iV, X) 2367.2376 2379.9720 2399.4574 2398.4324 2422.3609 2439.0243    10   c
```

Comment: Switch `arma::vec R, arma::mat V, arma::mat iV, arma::mat X` to `const arma::vec& R, const arma::mat& V, const arma::mat& iV, const arma::mat& X`.

Comment: R to Cpp may not always be 1 to 1 in the code as well (e.g. there may be a better way to approach the problem)

Comment: Thanks @coatless, I changed the arguments, but it barely changed the speed... (I have updated this in the question)

Comment: If I read this right then you are comparing _sparse_ to _dense_.  Apples and oranges?

Comment: The indexing is a big no no that you are doing. You can maintain that stack separately. Try using `.rows()` in place of `.elem()` and `.submat()`

Comment: Also, Dense != Sparse. Way different algorithms. Sorry I missed that. Thanks @eddelbuettel.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I converted the sparse matrix to dense for R too.

Comment: That's a good first step.  Now profile parts of the functions to find where the difference occurs.

Comment: @coatless `.rows()` does not help with speed. Also, `.submat()` can shed rows and cols together, but `.rows()` need two steps (followed with `.cols()`).

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel any suggestions about how to profile parts of the functions? Thanks.

Comment: @DaijiangLi sorry. What I meant was... Avoid using the index `idx` and use an id. So `.rows(0, n-1)` and `.submat( first_row, first_col, last_row, last_col )`

Comment: Also, why can't you use `arma::sp_mat` ?

Comment: @coatless did not use `.rows(0, n-1)` because I need to just remove one element for vector, and remove the jth row and column for mat, so `.submat( first_row, first_col, last_row, last_col )` will be really tedious. As for `sp_mat`, I tried but the way I managed to work does not work with `sp_mat`...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel After replacing `pinv()` with `inv()`, the `loop_cpp` is slightly faster `loop_R` (but not too much). But sometimes the matrix is singular and `inv()` will throw an error. How do you test whether a matrix is singular in RcppArmadillo and then write a if else?

Comment: Better.  Also the R code is already pretty vectorized so don't expect too much.  Computing the determinant should give you a clue.

Comment: You compiled with optimization enabled?

Comment: @manni66 not sure, I just used the default `Rcpp::sourceCpp()` function to compile the cpp file.

Comment: You are trying to translate a formula into algorithm steps which can sometimes work for numerical linear algebra but, for the most part, leads to very inefficient approaches.  Your case is in the second class.  The first rule of numerical linear algebra is "if your formula involves taking the inverse of a matrix you need to rethink your formula".  Read the J. Stat. Soft. paper we wrote on the computational methods in lme4 to see how it is done.

Comment: I think @DouglasBates is referring to his *Fitting Linear Mixed-Effects Models Using lme4* published on Oct 07, 2015: https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v067i01

Great read.

Comment: Yes.  Thank you for adding the link.